# Quelle est la différence entre « penser à », « penser de », et « penser + infinitif »

Tags: sens, verbes, prépositions, infinitif

Quelle est la différence entre ces trois utilisations du verbe *penser*?

1. *penser + de*
2. *penser + à*
3. *penser + verbe (infinitif)*

Si c'est possible, j’apprécierais des exemples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- *Penser de* exprime une opinion :

  > — Que penses-tu de ce livre ?
  >   — J'en pense qu'il est fantastique, je l'aime beaucoup. *(où "j'en pense" signifie "je pense de ce livre")*

  ou encore

  > — Que penses-tu d'aller déjeuner ?
  >   — Je meurs de faim, allons-y !
- *Penser à* exprime le fait d'avoir des pensées pour quelque chose ou quelqu'un

  > — Je suis content de te revoir. Tu m'as manqué, j'ai pensé à toi tous les jours !

  ou encore

  > — Pense à regonfler les pneus de la voiture avant de prendre la route !
  >   — Oui, c'est promis, j'y penserai. *(où "j'y pense" signifie "je pense à regonfler les pneus")*
- *Penser + verbe à l'infinitif* peut exprimer le fait de tenir pour réelle la chose induite par le verbe, ou exprimer une intention

  Croire réelle la chose induite par le verbe :

  > — J'étais allongé sur mon lit, et j'ai aperçu la silhouette d'un homme dans la pénombre. Je pensais rêver, puis j'ai brutalement compris qu'il s'agissait d'un cambrioleur.

  Exprimer une intention :

  > — Que penses-tu faire demain ?
  >   — Je suis épuisé. Demain, je pense me reposer, peut-être aller au cinéma, et me coucher tôt.