# Penser « à » faire quelque chose

Tags: prépositions

*Moi : Qu'est-ce que nous allons faire pour la soirée d'aujourd'hui ?*
*Mère : Je pense à faire un gâteau au chocolat, du riz au poulet...*

Are the French sentences correct? I need to write a conversation in French about an evening party at my house. I'm not sure if I can write "Je pense à faire".

[Me: "What are we going to do(cook) for today's evening party?"
Mother: "I am thinking of making chicken rice, a cake, ..."]

Comment: It's "penser + verv in the infinitive form" (no preposition in this case). This question has already an answer on [French Language](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6987/358) where difference between *penser à* / *penser de*/ "*penser* + infinitive" is explained.

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe 'penser' n'est pas toujours suivi des mêmes prépositions.
Pour citer le forum [etudes-litteraires.com](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/post280804.html#p280804) :

> **Penser que + complétive.**
>   Synon. de être d'avis (que), juger, estimer, considérer (que).
>   L'infinitif complément équivaut à une proposition dont le sujet est le même que celui de la proposition principale : je pense tourner la page et quitter mon travail = je pense que je vais tourner la page et quitter mon travail = je suis d'avis de tourner la page et quitter mon travail. Ma décision est quasiment prise.
>
> **Penser à**
>   Appliquer son esprit à un objet abstrait ou concret, présent ou non. Synon. réfléchir, songer (à), se concentrer (sur) : je pense à tourner la page et à quitter mon travail = je réfléchis à tourner la page et quitter mon travail. Ma décision n'est pas prise.

Donc dans ton exemple, j'utiliserais plutôt "je pense faire un gâteau", qui a le même sens que "je pense que je vais faire un gâteau".