# L'utilisation de « d' » au lieu de « que je me » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, infinitif

J'ai commencé à dire à un ami, « je pense que je me débrouille ... », et il a répondu que c'est mieux à dire « je pense *de me debrouiller* » comme le plus correct ou plus naturel façon parler. Je connais ni un règle / de la direction ni comment on le décrit.

Aujourd'hui, une autre amie m'a envoyé un message disant, « je crois d'être disponible ... » — au lieu de « je crois que je suis disponible ... »

Quelles — si elles existent — sont les règles, et dans quelles situations on parle comme ça ?

Comment: ??? Non, *de* ne marche pas du tout dans ces phrases. Ils sont français, ces amis ? Et ils disent vraiment *de*, et pas « je pense me débrouiller » et « je crois être disponible » ?

Comment: D'accord avec Gilles, tes amis n'ont pas l'air de bien parler français, tu devrais te méfier de leur conseils...

Comment: Tu peux en effet dire, à peine, "je pense me débrouiller", "je crois être disponible"... mais cela semble peu naturel dans un langage parlé : en effet, cela donne une impression d'un effort tortueux et injustifié pour éviter une clause relative (la clause avec "que").  Cette "antipathie" pour cette clause relative n'est pas appropriée.  C'est toi qui as raison !  (A propos, en parlant du futur tu dirais "je pense que je **serai** disponible... à la différence de l'anglais, tu ne peux pas utiliser le temps présent pour le futur ici).

Comment: La formule " je crois que je suis disponible " pose des doutes elle meme au vu de l'état conjugatif du verbe qui doit selon moi rephrasé au mode subjonctif "je crois que je sois", a moins que les deux formules peuvent bien s'appliquer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many verbs that may be followed by a plain infinitive. Among them are the verbs: **affirmer; croire; dire; prétendre**. (Il y a beaucoup de verbes qui peuvent être suivis d'un infinitif sans préposition).

The **verb+plain infinitive** construction is only possible when the subject of the infinitive is the same as that of the verb which governs it. When the subject is different, **que** and a clause must be used. (Cette construction n'est possible que lorsque le sujet de l'infinitif est le même que celui du verbe qui le gouverne. Lorsque le sujet est différent, que et une clause doit être utilisée.)

> Elle a cru distinguer une chose verte.
>
> Je crois être malade (cf. Je crois qu'elle malade.)
>
> Si quelqu'un a dit être le colonel, ce n'est qu'un imposteur.

Even where the subjects are the same, the infinitive construction is most often replaced by the construction with **que** and a clause in colloquial French. The infinitive construction is only used in rather formal speech. (Même là où les sujets sont les mêmes, la construction avec l'infinitif sans préposition est le plus souvent remplacée par la construction avec que et une clause en français courant. La construction à l'infini n'est utilisée que dans un discours plutôt formel.)

> cf. Je crois m'être enrhumé. Je crois **que** je me suis enrhumé.

In any case the use of **de** is erroneous here with the verb croire. (En tout cas l'utilisation de *de* est erronée ici avec le verbe croire.)

With penser there several infinitive constructions:

> penser faire = intend to do; penser à faire = think of doing (idea occurs); penser à = think about.

See the discussion here:

[Quelle est la différence entre « penser à », « penser de », et « penser + infinitif »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6987/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-penser-%C3%A0-penser-de-et-penser-infini)

and the article

https://www.frantastique.com/en/french-grammar/penser-a-ou-penser-de

Also

> penser garde à faire = take care to do; prendre garde de faire = take care not to do, beware of doing

Comment: Les verbes de perception sont suivis d'un infinitif dont le sujet réel n'est pas celui de la principale. Par exemple : « Je l'ai vu lire les lettres. » La règle que tu énonces, telle qu'elle est formulée, n'est donc pas correcte.