# What’s the difference between [penser à] [infinitive] and [penser] [infinitive]?

Tags: grammaire, sens, synonymes

> Je pense à changer de travail.
>   Je pense aller chez mes parents.

I saw these two sentences. I wonder what’s the difference between [penser à] [infinitive] and [penser] [infinitive].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this [already has an answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6987/358), as this other question has answers in French and is more general I will try to make a short point in English here.

There's very little difference between the two uses in your two examples. If you say:

- *je pense à changer de travail*

or:

- *je pense changer de travail*

  it means that you are thinking about it in either case.

Saying *je pense **à** changer de travail* just shows you might be thinking more intensely about it but in neither case have you made up your mind.

The same can be said about:

- *Je pense aller chez mes parents*

and:

- *Je pense à aller chez mes parents.*

But in that case *je pense aller chez mes parents* is probably much more common. Personally I would not say *je pense à aller chez mes parents* independently of the context but I see no reason why it could not be said.

**But** in the sentence:

- Il faut que je pense à aller chez mes parents.

where the sentence is introduced by *il faut que* ("I must")  having *à* is mandatory, because *il faut que* indicates you have already taken a decision and *penser à* in that sentence **does not mean** "to think" but "**to remember**".

Comment: No, there's a huge difference between “je pense à changer …” (I'm thinking about changing, but that doesn't mean I'm planning to do it, it just means that I don't completely reject it) and “je pense changer …” (my current plan is to change, I may still take a different decision but it's likely that I will do it).

Answer (score 2):

**"Penser à"** is the translation of "to think about".

You can think about someone or something (in this case about *doing something*).

So it works for:

> Je pense à mon chien = I'm thinking about my dog
>
> Je pense à changer de travail = I'm thinking about changing jobs
>
> Je pense à ce que j'aimerais faire demain = I'm thinking about what I'd like to do tomorrow

**"Penser"** is "to think" and its main use is "penser que" = "to think that".

> Je pense que tu as raison = I think (that) you are right
>
> Je pense que je devrais changer de travail = I think (that) I should change jobs

We don't really use "penser" as is, like "Oh sorry, I was just thinking", we would say "Oh désolé, je réfléchissais".

**"Penser" + infinitive** is a specific construction.

The best translation is, as Rémi said, with the future:

> Je pense venir chez toi demain = I think (that) I'll come to your house tomorrow
>
> Je pense changer de travail (bientôt) = I think (that) I'm going to change jobs (soon)

Note that you can use the "que" construction I explained above to carry the exact same meaning, and that's probably what most people do:

> Je pense *que je viendrai* chez toi demain
>
> Je pense *que je vais changer* de travail (bientôt)

---

Note that there are many uses of this verb, for example **"penser" + something**, or some constructions like "je pense comme toi" (I agree, I'm thinking the same), or "bien pensé" (well-designed, well-engineered, thought through): https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/penser

Answer (score 0):

The sentence

> Je penser à changer de travail.

Is completely wrong in French, you can't have a pronoun followed by an infinitive.

The right way to write it would be

> Je pense à changer de travail
>
> J'ai pensé à changer de travail

In French there is a small difference between

> Je pense changer de travail **And** Je pense à changer de travail

The first one means that you've already taken your decision and that it's going to happen : **I think I'll change jobs**

The second one is more hypothetical, where no decision has been made yet : **I'm thinking about changing jobs**

Comment: To be honnest I understand no difference between both your examples with "changer de job". In both cases there's nothing concrete, just an idea.